# Errors when running gulp serve when using SharePoint Framework Office UI Fabric Components tutorial

Tags: spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

Should I need to worry about these lint errors in Using gulp serve in the SharePoint Framework Office UI Fabric Components tutorial?

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Using-Office-UI-Fabric-Components

```
    Error - tslint - src\webparts\documentCardExample\components\DocumentCardExample.tsx(10,10): error no-unused-variable: unused variable: 'css'
    Error - tslint - src\webparts\documentCardExample\components\DocumentCardExample.tsx(12,8): error no-unused-variable: unused variable: 'styles'
    Error - tslint - src\webparts\documentCardExample\components\DocumentCardExample.tsx(29,6): error trailing-comma: trailing comma
    Error - tslint - src\webparts\documentCardExample\components\DocumentCardExample.tsx(19,15): error typedef: expected call-signature: 'render' to have a typedef
    Error - tslint - src\webparts\documentCardExample\components\DocumentCardExample.tsx(20,7): error prefer-const: Identifier 'previewProps' never appears on the LHS of an assignment - use const instead of let for its declaration.
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are all valid lint errors which should go away if you make the following changes in your `DocumentCardExample.tsx`

1) Remove the following import statements as they are not being used anymore:

```
import { css } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import styles from '../ShowDocuments.module.scss';
```

3) Replace the the render method in the tutorial with this one:

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
    const previewProps: IDocumentCardPreviewProps = {
      previewImages: [
        {
          previewImageSrc: require('document-preview.png'),
          iconSrc: require('icon-ppt.png'),
          width: 318,
          height: 196,
          accentColor: '#ce4b1f'
        }
      ]
    };

    return (
      <DocumentCard onClickHref='http://bing.com'>
        <DocumentCardPreview { ...previewProps } />
        <DocumentCardTitle title='Revenue stream proposal fiscal year 2016 version02.pptx'/>
        <DocumentCardActivity
          activity='Created Feb 23, 2016'
          people={
            [
              { name: 'Kat Larrson', profileImageSrc: require('avatar-kat.png') }
            ]
          }
          />
      </DocumentCard>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Should this be used in the Tutorial itself rather than the current render() method ?

Comment: Yes, this is the same code in the tutorial tweaked to get rid of the lint errors.